# How to make the color of the parent and child window same?

Tags: c++, winapi

I hardly know anything about windows.h library, but I have to make an application using it (long story). Anyways I would really appreciate if you can be patient with me on this one. My child window contains only some static text to be displayed on the parent window, but the colors are different how do I make them same? I have tried googling but i don't seem to get a hang of anything. Oh and I am using C++.

I saw this on MSDN

`HRESULT EnableThemeDialogTexture(
  _In_ HWND  hwnd,
  _In_ DWORD dwFlags
);`

but not sure where to use it.

My handle to the child window is start.

```
HRESULT EnableThemeDialogTexture(start,ETDT_DISABLE);
```

I tried this but I get errors such as

[Error] 'ETDT_DISABLE' was not declared in this scope

[Error] expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]

i have my backgroud as

```
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_GRADIENTINACTIVECAPTION+1);
```

my child window

```
switch(Message) 
{
    case WM_CREATE: 
    start = CreateWindow("STATIC","some text here",
    WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,200,100,300,100,hwnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);       
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY: {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
```

my parent window

```
hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,"WindowClass","                                                                                        SHOPAHOLIC",
    WS_VISIBLE|WS_SYSMENU| WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, /* x */
    CW_USEDEFAULT, /* y */
    740, /* width */
    580, /* height */
    NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL);
```

Comment: Show some code and be more explicit, it's hard to understand what you want.

Comment: @MichaelWalz can you please take a look again. thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

Handle the [WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787524(v=vs.85).aspx) message. (At the end of that page there's an example to do exactly what you're asking.)